# Bind multiple events to jQuery 'live' method

Tags: jquery

jQuery's 'live' method is unable to handle multiple events. Does anyone know of a good workaround to attach multiple events to a function that polls current and future elements? Or am I stuck using duplicate live methods for each event handler I need?

Example - I am trying to do something like:

```
$('.myclass').live('change keypress blur', function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: are you trying to attach multiple handlers to the same event? or are you trying to attach a handler for many different events?

Comment: It sounds like he wants multiple events in the same handler, as if you could do $("a").live(["click","mouseover","doubleclick"], function() { //do stuff here}.  Which you can't.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like "$('.myclass').live("click keypress blur", function(){..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**From jQuery 1.7**, "on" function is what you're looking for :

```
$("a").on({
    click: function() {
        // do something on click
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
       // do something on mouseenter
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
         // do something on mouseleave
    }
});
```

Answer (score 19):

As of jQuery 1.4.1 [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) can accept multiple, space-separated events, similar to the functionality provided in [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).  For example, we can "live bind" the mouseover and mouseout events at the same time like so:

```
$('.hoverme').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

In jQuery 1.7 there is an API that allow you to do it easily...

```
$(".myClass").on({
    click: function(){
         alert("You click on me!");
    },
    mouseenter: function(){
         alert("Do you want click on me?");
    }
});
```

In my opinion this method is completely efficient and gathering all abilities that you can use in element's event....

Take a look at this page [`.on()` [ jQuery 1.7 API ]](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
("#button").bind("click keyup", function(){

// your code goes here

})
```