# Event handler on multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind multiple events to jQuery 'live' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646187/bind-multiple-events-to-jquery-live-method)

I have the following function:

```
$("td.delivered").click(function() {

        $(this).html($("<input/>", {
          id: 'inp',
          style: 'width:80px;',
          placeholder: "YYYY-MM-DD",
          change: function() {
            selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
          },
          blur: function() {
            selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
          },
          onkeypress=="Return": function() { // pseudo-code
            selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
          }
        })
        );
}
```

The following works, what would be  a better way to write it?

```
          change: function() {
            selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
          },
          blur: function() {
            selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
          },
          onkeypress: function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
            }
          }
```

How would I write this more concisely, making the `selectdone` function fire on `change`, `blur`, and `return`?

Comment: why do you need both blur and change? blur covers a value being changed or not

Comment: @ianpgall Blur would account for if a user clicks on another element, in which case I'd want the function to fire. For example, if you click your user menu in StackOverflow, and then click elsewhere on the page again the user menu will disappear.

Comment: oh i understand that, but that means you don't need to bind "change" as well. all "change" is, is when an element is unfocused and the value has changed. "blur" is simply when an element is unfocused.

Comment: no problem. it's not too important, but it can be redundant if you use both blur and change to execute the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).html($("<input/>", {
      id: 'inp',
      style: 'width:80px;',
      placeholder: "YYYY-MM-DD"
  });

$('input', this).bind('change blur keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.type != 'keypress' || e.keyCode == 13){
        selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't account for the pseudo 'Return' function

Comment: @maxhud thank you, could you please write the complete function and I will accept your answer

Comment: here it is. this should work just fine

Comment: @maxhud: hmm, so this actually does not work. It will DELETE a row if it's value is None instead of keeping the value (whereas the above function that I included does this correctly). I don't know enough about js to know why, but the action in your function is not the exact same as the one I've provided above.

Comment: Try that. I accidentally applied the function to the container of the inputs instead of each input. Now 'this' inside the bind function, will be any input inside the container rather than the container

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind`:

```
  $(this).html($("<input/>", {
      id: 'inp',
      style: 'width:80px;',
      placeholder: "YYYY-MM-DD",
      change: function() {
        selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
      }
  });

  $(this).bind('blur keypress change', function(e){
     selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
  });
```

You may need to modify your code for different events. Notice that to know which event is currently triggered, you would use `e.type`

Comment: this doesn't account for the pseudo 'Return' function

Comment: it does, but not so easily. you have to check the event type, and then see if it is "keypress" or whatever, then check the event's keycode for "13" as that is the return button's keycode.