# Is it possible to combine Keydown with Live Click function?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a WordPress template. The following code works fine with "Click Function". But now I want to add keyboard shortcut to this function, so that visitor will get choice for both mouse click and keyboard shortcut to perform same function. I tried to apply [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872560/1312563) after `e(".bookmark").live("click", function () {` line but it didn't solve the problem, Instead it broke the button too.

A little help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
function whatever_do_js(e, t) {
    loadingImg = e.prev();
    loadingImg.show();
    beforeImg = e.prev().prev();
    beforeImg.hide();
    url = document.location.href.split("#")[0];
    params = e.attr("href").replace("?", "") + "&ajax=1";
    if (t) {
        jQuery.get(url, params, function (t) {
            e.parent().html(t);
            if (typeof whatever_after_ajax == "function") {
                whatever_after_ajax(e)
            }
            loadingImg.hide()
        })
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    e(".bookmark").live("click", function () {
        dhis = e(this);
        whatever_do_js(dhis, 1);
        return false
    })
})
```

Comment: What's the keyboard shortcut you want to use?

Comment: 'B' for bookmark is the key I'd like to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(selector).bind("click keydown", function () {
    // Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank for you little tip. I tried the following code, there are no errors in console but both enter button and click aren't working
`jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
        dhis = e(this);
    jQuery(".bookmark").bind("click keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "keydown" && e.which == 13)
        fancy_do_js(dhis, 1);
        return false
    })
})
`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help you, Bind multiple events to jQuery 'live' method([Bind multiple events to jQuery 'live' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646187/bind-multiple-events-to-jquery-live-method))